# Extracting src from Beautifulsoup Tag

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I was trying to scrape newegg for product name, description, price and image using beautifulsoup. I have got following bs4.element.Tag type and I want to extract "src" link from tag. Following is my tag:

```
df = <a class="itemImage" href="http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16875169194&amp;cm_re=Samsung_edge-_-75-169-194-_-Product" id="img_75-169-194" title='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty'>\n<img alt='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty' src="http://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll200/75-169-194-04.jpg" title='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty'/>\n</a>
```

How can I extract

```
src="http://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll200/75-169-194-04.jpg"
```

from this tag? I tried

```
df.attrs['src']
```

but I received Keyerror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The src is in the *img* tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
tag = """<a class="itemImage" href="http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16875169194&amp;cm_re=Samsung_edge-_-75-169-194-_-Product" id="img_75-169-194" title='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty'>\n<img alt='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty' src="http://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll200/75-169-194-04.jpg" title='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty'/>\n</a>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(tag,"lxml")

src = soup.img["src"]
```

Which will give you:

```
http://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll200/75-169-194-04.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

try regular expressions in python
reference
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

```
import re
s = """
    <a class="itemImage" href="http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16875169194&amp;cm_re=Samsung_edge-_-75-169-194-_-Product" id="img_75-169-194" title='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty'>\n<img alt='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty' src="http://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll200/75-169-194-04.jpg" title='Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge Dual SIM Unlocked Smart Phone, Dual Edge 5.5" AMOLED Display, black Color, 32GB Storage 4GB RAM International Version - No US Warranty'/>\n</a>
    """
src_list = re.findall("src=[^\s]*", s)
```

output:

```
src_list = ['src="http://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll200/75-169-194-04.jpg"']
```