# Scraping multiple data with same class name using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I recently posted here, but I was not able to solve the problem so I'm asking again.
I'm trying to scrape this website for 'Recent Sales' section (all the addresses): https://www.compass.com/agents/irene-vuong/

My code looks like this:

```
listings = []
for item in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'uc-listingCard-title'}):
    listings.append(item.get_text(strip=True))

print(listings)
```

My output is :

```
['256-258 Wyckoff Street', '1320 Glenwood Road', '1473 East 55th Street', '145 Winter Avenue', '25-02 Brookhaven Avenue']
```

However expected out would be:

```
['256-258 Wyckoff Street', '1320 Glenwood Road', '1473 East 55th Street', '145 Winter Avenue', '25-02 Brookhaven Avenue', '352 94th Street', '1754 West 12th Street', '2283 E 23rd st', '2063 Brown Street, '3423 Avenue U', '2256 Stuart Street']
```

Which contians all address as the class name is same as

``````
<a class="uc-listingCard-title" href="`````" data-tn="listingCard-label-address"> adress here </a>
``````

I don't understand why my code only gets first part but not the whole addresses when it has same class name.

Thank you in advance for any help.

++++ With suggestions:

```
for item in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'uc-listingCard-content'}):
    new = item.find('a', attrs={'class': 'uc-listingCard-title'})
    print(new.text)
```

I still only get the current listing addresses but NOT ALL addresses.

Comment: Can you share the relevant part of the HTML source code? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scraping data with multiple same class name using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60515908/scraping-data-with-multiple-same-class-name-using-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.compass.com/agents/irene-vuong/'
url = requests.get(url)
tags = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html')
smaple_list=[]
for tag in tags.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'uc-listingCard-content'}):
    new_tag = tag.find('a', attrs={'class': 'uc-listingCard-title'})
    print(new_tag.text)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi!!! It does get all the address, but I only want to scrap the text out, so I did .text but I get an attribute error of "ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?". I tried "find" but I get different error, what do I need to do? Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: take a look:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38053464/extracting-src-from-beautifulsoup-tag

Comment: So I still get the current listing, but not all sales listings. I want to get "Recent Sales" addresses, which comes after current listing...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209010/discussion-between-sarah-kim-and-yehezkel-horoviz).

Comment: Are you still there?